# Does the principal value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix} dx$ vanish?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

The integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix} dx$ diverges. I have read (in a wikipedia article) that the principal value of this integral vanishes: $P \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix} dx = 0$. How can one see that?

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Personally, I think this is nonsense on stilts. *However*, if you look into any case where this is being used, I suspect you will find that a closer analysis will reveal an interpretation that makes sense. But without that context, it does not.

Comment: You need to decide how to regularize the integral first, e.g., by evaluating it over $[-N,N]$ (and eventually letting $N\rightarrow\infty$), or by multiplying the integrand by $\exp(-\eta x^2)$ (and eventually letting $\eta\rightarrow 0$), or whatever.  Then you can talk about doing things with the result (like taking the principal value, or convolving with another function, or what have you).  Without some context, a divergent integral doesn't represent a particular divergent *process* (going, going, gone)... it's just meaningless.

Comment: Thanks! How do you go on after evaluating the integral over $\left[ -N,N \right]$? The result is: $2 \sin(N)$. How do you take the limit, where $N$ goes to infinity?

Comment: I edited my original post to focus on the actual question.

Comment: $\lim_{N\to\infty}2\sin N$ doesn't exist, so the principal value (by this interpretation) doesn't exist.

Comment: Which wikipedia article? Knowing that would help to contextualize this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral can be regularized using the [integral analogue of Cesàro summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation#Ces.C3.A0ro_summability_of_an_integral).  By definition we have

$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{C} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix}\,dx &= \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{1}{a} \int_0^a \int_{-y}^{y} e^{ix}\,dx\,dy \\
&= \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{2}{a} \int_0^a \sin y\,dy \\
&= \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{2}{a} (1 - \cos a) \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
$$

Perhaps this is what the article was referring to?

Comment: Informally this says that the oscillations "cancel out" in the average.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the this as a the distribution:

$$P.V.\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixt}dx\right)_{t=1}$$

Now the distribution needs to be tested against test functions as:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P.V.\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixt}dx\right)\phi(t)dt$$

Which is, because of the definition of Principal Value:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{e^{ixt}}{it}\right]_{-N}^{N}\phi(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^{iNt}-e^{-iNt}}{it}\right)\phi(t)dt$$

Now we change variables to $y=Nt$ so we have, $dt=dy/N$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2sen(y)}{y}\lim_{N\to\infty}\phi(y/N)dy$$

Finally, because $\phi$ is a test function, it is continuos:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P.V.\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixt}dx\right)\phi(t)dt=2\pi\phi(0)$$

Which tells you that:

$$P.V.\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixt}dx\right)_{t=1}=\left(2\pi\delta(t)\right)_{t=1}=0$$

Now the Dirac Delta is a Distribution whose converges to $0$ at every point but zero.